# Code Covereage Overview in TFS different from .coverage file

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, code-coverage

We are trying to add visual studio coverage to our CI and so far it is working, but when I open the build, it displays a different coverage for the downloadable .coverage file.

This is how it looks in the overview:
[image]

and this is the downloaded .coverage file, when i open it in VS:

[image]

as you can see, the absolute covered lines and blocks are the same, but it seams that locally i have another number of overall lines and therefore the percentage is much higher. I am pretty sure that the local version is the correct one, as Resharper also covers 67%. I read, that building in release can change the coverage, I also built in debug/release locally and in the CI, but the coverage stays more or less the same (0.1 % off).

What we also do is, that we run our integrationtests on a different machine, so I had to copy the pdb files over to the other machine to be able to cover the tests over there. This also is working and the results get merged correctly but somhow the overall line/block count is still off.

We are using TFS 2017 and VS 2019.

Did anybody have the same problems? Is there a workaround without having to use a third party cover tool?